# I am not getting any response with flutter

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

When I test the php codes with postman, I get the answer "success". But when we do it with flutter, the code does not enter the if structure or the else structure, the prints do not work. I tried without json_encode but it still didn't work.When I try with Dio, I see the same unresponsiveness again.What can I do?

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'login.dart';

abstract class LoginViewModel extends State<Login> {
  final TextEditingController email_controller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController pass_controller = TextEditingController();
  Future<void> fetchLogin() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://********/canlidestek/login.php"),
          body: {"email": email_controller.text, "password": pass_controller.text});

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        print(data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include_once "config.php";
    if($_POST){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM livesup WHERE email = '{$email}'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    
                $status = "Online";
                $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE livesup SET status = '{$status}' WHERE unique_id = {$row['unique_id']}");
                if($sql2){
                    $_SESSION['unique_id'] = $row['unique_id'];
                    echo json_encode("success");
                }else{
                    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again!";
                }
        
        }else{
            echo "$email - This email not Exist!";
        }
    }else{
        echo "All input fields are required!";
    }
    }else
    {
            echo "no data post";

    }
?>
```

Comment: Is PHP Server online, or on your local machine ?

Comment: please provide catch print log.

Comment: i am using xampserver

Comment: Since you using xamp , What is the base url that you covered with "******" in provider code ?

Comment: are you calling this method from anywhere? cal you put print statement `print(inside fetchLogin method)` to see if it gets printed. I know it is really silly suggestion but sometimes it happens.

Comment: if the base URL is LocalHost, you need to change it to your laptop IP ,

Comment: My ip address is in the *******

Comment: yes i run this function when i click the login button on my ui page

Comment: When I tried to enter the URL from the phone, I realized that I could not enter it. What should I do to open this URL from another phone?

Comment: maybe start "send data to php". can you insert echo "something"; to php's firstline. and check any response? if you can't see nothing maybe hint is flutter log. like logcat

Comment: I write an answer to describe the problem for you,

Comment: which Php version you are using, and are you using any frameworks like laravel or somtehing?

Comment: I am not using laravel. The php version I am using is 8.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

Since you are not using an online server, and the api working great with post man.
we can say that the problem is in connection between your android device and php server (Xampp) which is your laptop.

## First Solution to try:

if you using local host on flutter code, change it to laptop IP Address, and the android device and laptop have to be on same network.

## Second Solution if the first not working:

you have to make sure to shutdown windows firewall, it will block the request in some cases.

And Make Sure your server accessible from outside devices.

Comment: thank you . I realized that the error is here. I will try

Comment: Good luck, tell me if it not working to search for another solutions.